# Calculate pairwise operation of each element in a list (python)

Tags: python, numpy

How would I perform pairwise operations of each matrix within list a?
I'm expecting 10 new variables (n*(n-1))/2 where n is the number of elements in list a. (5*(5-1))/2 = 10.

How would I do this in a way so that it scales with any number of n?

```
# list of matrices
a = [matrix([[ 1.1],[2.2]]),
    matrix([[3.3],[ 4.4]]),
    matrix([[5.5],[7.7]]),
    matrix([[6.6],[9.9]]),
    matrix([[8.8],[0.1]])]

b1 = a[0] - a[1] # no need to do a[0] - a[0]
b2 = a[0] - a[2]
b3 = a[0] - a[3]
b4 = a[0] - a[4]
b5 = a[1] - a[2] # no need to do a[1] - a[0]
b6 = a[1] - a[3]
b7 = a[1] - a[4]
b8 = a[2] - a[3]
b9 = a[2] - a[4]
b10 = a[3] - a[4]
```

Comment: Please provide more context. What have you tried? How knowledgeable are you on python? Do you know loops?

Comment: Why do you need new variables instead of a list?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
length = len(a)
i = 0
for x in range(length):
    for y in range(length):
        if x >= y : continue
        i += 1
        exec(f'b{i}=a[{x}]-a[{y}]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# list of matrices
a = [matrix([[ 1.1],[2.2]]),
    matrix([[3.3],[ 4.4]]),
    matrix([[5.5],[7.7]]),
    matrix([[6.6],[9.9]]),
    matrix([[8.8],[0.1]])]
b = []
#a1 goes through everything except last
for i,a1 in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    #a2 starts after a1 and goes through everything
    for a2 in a[i+1:]:
        b.append(a1-a2)
        #differences are collected
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your question is quite unclear as you're referencing a 3 dimensional list as if it were 2 dimensional, but hopefully this what you are after.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
a = [
    [[1.1], [2.2]],
    [[3.3], [4.4]],
    [[5.5], [6.6]]
]

c = len(a)
p = 0
    
output = []
for i, x in enumerate(combinations(chain.from_iterable(a),2)):
    if p<=c:
        c-=1
        output.append(x[0][0]-x[1][0])
    else:
        p+=1
        c=len(a)
```

Theoretically you could split unpack this, but you really should not

```
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10 = output
```

Output

```
[-1.1,
 -2.1999999999999997,
 -3.3000000000000003,
 -4.4,
 -1.0999999999999996,
 -2.2,
 -3.3,
 -1.1000000000000005,
 -2.2,
 -1.0999999999999996]
```